# View author field (image) in a node view

Tags: nodes, entities, media

I have created a image field in the user account. How can I add the image of the author to the display of each node?

Answer (score 2):

You may do that using a Views Block and place it in the Main Content block region, right after the content block. Also, you'll need to create a relationship between the node and it's author, so only the correct user will be displayed. Below is a screenshot of a work I've done using Views for Drupal 7.42 that I think is close to what you're looking for:
[image: Views Author]

1 - Create a new Block View to view Users (not Content)

2 - Filter Criteria should say User: Active (Yes)

3 - There is a default sort Criteria item. Remove it since it doesn't matter.

4 - Add a Relationship: Choose "User: Content authored"

5 - Add a Contextual Filter: Chose "Content: Nid"

6 - In the configuration options for the newly added Content: Nid, choose these options:
WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE:
Provide default value
In the Select box, choose Content ID From URL.

WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS AVAILABLE OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED
Specify validation criteria
Validator select box: Content
Content Types: choose the content types you want the view to work with.
Filter Value Format: Node ID
Action to take if the filter value does not validate: Hide View

7 - Save the View.

8 - Go to Structure -> Blocks and configure the block to show on the types of content you want it to show on and position it wherever you want it to appear.

9 - Done.

Comment: Could you please add the contextual filters and relationships screenshots?

Comment: I've edited the answer with a more precise walktrough.